# find ALL applicable methods in R

Tags: r, object

For looking up methdos for a particular class, there is *methods* in R, e.g.

```
> methods(class="lm")
 [1] add1           alias          anova          case.names     coerce        
 [6] confint        cooks.distance deviance       dfbeta         dfbetas       
[11] drop1          dummy.coef     effects        extractAIC     family        
[16] formula        hatvalues      influence      initialize     kappa         
[21] labels         logLik         model.frame    model.matrix   nobs          
[26] plot           predict        print          proj           qr            
[31] residuals      rstandard      rstudent       show           simulate      
[36] slotsFromS3    summary        variable.names vcov
```

Unfortunately this does not list all applicable methods: for instance *AIC* is missing in the above list, and I guess there are yet many more. From the *AIC* documentation, it can be concluded that it is applicable because it asks for a *logLik* method, but this can not be concluded from the output of *methods*.

Is there some way to find out which methods an object accepts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I have figured out why *AIC* cannot be found as a method of *lm*, even though it is applicable. Instead of deleting my question, I here provide an answer in case others might find it helpful, too.

*AIC* is not an S4 "generic" method, but uses the S3 object mechanism which is based on naming conventions (resolved by *UseMethod*):

```
> # not an S4 method:
> isGeneric("AIC")
[1] FALSE
> # S3 methods that looks up with UseMethod():
> AIC
function (object, ..., k = 2) 
UseMethod("AIC")
> methods(AIC)
[1] AIC.default* AIC.logLik*
```

This means that *AIC* calls *AIC.logLik* if called on an object of class *logLik*, but on all other cases it calls *AIC.default*, which tries to call *logLik* on the given object:

```
# internal method (*) => ':::' operator required to list code
> stats:::AIC.default
function (object, ..., k = 2) 
{
    ll <- if (isNamespaceLoaded("stats4")) 
        stats4::logLik
    else logLik
    if (!missing(...)) {
      # [...]
    }
    else {
        lls <- ll(object)
        -2 * as.numeric(lls) + k * attr(lls, "df")
    }
}
```

As this is hidden in the implementation of *AIC.default* and is not apparent from the naming convention, it is impossible for `methods(class="lm")` to figure out that *AIC* is a method of *lm*.